# What is ruby-build for?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm trying to install jekyll to create my own github page referring to other bloggers. Many of them install rbenv to manage different versions of ruby on mac, but also install ruby-build. No one actually explains what this is for. I'd appreciate if anyone knows about it.

Answer (score 3):

My basic understanding is that `rbenv` manages the different versions and lets you pick and choose at will. `ruby-build` is the actual tool that downloads the different versions.

[ruby-build docs](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build)

> ruby-build is a tool that downloads and compiles various versions of
> Ruby. It is available as a plugin for rbenv that provides the `rbenv install` command, or as a standalone program.

[rbenv docs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F)

> - Provide support for specifying application-specific Ruby versions.
> - Let you change the global Ruby version on a per-user basis.
> - Allow you to override the Ruby version with an environment variable.